# Mongoose Validations/Hooks based on most recent record in table (if exists) | Model for a Bank Account

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am designing a bank account schema, which looks like follows:

```
const bankAccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    transactionType: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['credit', 'debit']
        required: true
    },
    amount: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    balance: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0,
        required: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

const BankAccount = mongoose.model('BankAccount', bankAccountSchema)
```

As far as the user is concerned, they can only add or remove `amount` (positive or negative) from the account. The `balance` column is supposed to keep track of the running total in the account. In the route, I already have code that prevents the user from withdrawing more money than he has in the account but I am wondering if it is possible to set up the following validations/hooks for my model as well:

1. Before saving, automatically update the `balance` and `transactionType` (`credit` if `amount` is positive, `debit` if `amount` is negative) columns based on `amount` and previous record's `balance` (if exists) so that records can be created simply by the command `new BankAccount({ amount: 100 }).save()` without explicitly stating appropriate `balance` or `transactionType`.
2. Should be unable to withdraw more than is available in account i.e. if the previous record's `balance` is 100 then `amount` for a new record can never be less than -100.

Both (1) and (2) require accessing the previous record in the table (if exists) before save. Can this be done or do I have to depend solely on my route for validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using an `async` validator and the `this.constructor` keyword like follows:

```
const bankAccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    transactionType: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['credit', 'debit']
        required: true
    },
    amount: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    balance: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0,
        required: true,
        async validate(balance) {
            // Make DB calls here
            console.log(await this.constructor.countDocuments())
        }
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

const BankAccount = mongoose.model('BankAccount', bankAccountSchema)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. `Mongoose` now provides `some middlewares/hooks` to validate your `schema`. For your requirement you can use `schema.pre` `hook`. It will execute before `saving` the record.

Here is the example of that

```
const schema = new Schema(..);
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
 if (foo()) {
   console.log('calling next!');
   // `return next();` will make sure the rest of this function doesn't run
   /*return*/ next();
 }
   // Unless you comment out the `return` above, 'after next' will print
   console.log('after next');
});
```

You can read more about `middlewares` [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work because I will be trying to access a record from the BankAccount model before it has been defined with Mongoose.model.